# Initialize generic data structure at runtime?

Tags: java, generics

I have implemented a generic data structure that holds comparable objects (ints, floats, strings, etc.).   The signature looks like

```
public class MyStruct<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

And during runtime, I am presented with a string input that could represent any comparable data type.

How could I instantiate the data structure according to whatever type the input string represents? Or should I change the data structure to accommodate this kind of situation?

So if the input is "4", I would like to instantiate with

```
MyStruct<Integer> struct = new Struct<Integer>();
```

and if the input is "4.0",

```
MyStruct<Float> struct = new Struct<Float>();
```

and so on to support all comparable types.

Comment: Give some more information. Show some code samples - otherwise it is not really clear what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

At runtime, there is no difference between `MyStruct<Integer>` and `MyStruct<Float>`; the type information is available at compile-time only, and thereafter is dropped due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

You could implement methods in your class to manually perform type conversion and checking, if you wish, but I do not believe there is a way to adapt your class as written to use a type inferred at runtime.